# What is the difference between moveFromLocal v/s put and CopyToLocal v/s get in hadoop hdfs command

Tags: hadoop

Basically what is the major difference between moveFromLocal and copyToLocal instead of using put and get command in CLI of hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

**moveFromLocal:** Similar to put command, except that the source localsrc is deleted after it’s copied.

**copyToLocal:** Similar to get command, except that the destination is restricted to a local file reference.

[Source](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyToLocal).